# Postman mock servers - Mock a response with a random 10-digit number

Tags: random, mocking, postman, response

I’m using Postman 8.12.1.  I’m creating a mock server and trying to set up my mock response for a certain request so that the response returns a random 10 digit number.  However, the only pre-built function I can find is “randomInt”

[image]

That seems to have a very limited range.  Is there a way I can configure my response to return a random integer that has 10 digits?  It is fine if the leading digits are zeroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$timestamp](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/variables-list/) which will return 10 digits number:

> The current UNIX timestamp in seconds   (as 1562757107)

You have similar options as  [$randomBankAccount](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/variables-list/)

> A random 8-digit bank account number

Or [$randomPhoneNumber](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/variables-list/)

> A random 10-digit phone number (as 700-008-5275)

Answer (score 0):

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/8296678/UUy65Pz5

Postman doesn't allow to update mock server dynamically , but due to its sweet API first design , we can use Postman API to update the environment variables and this will reflect in the mock server response

Please see the attached public collection to know how to do this .

[image]

Here i am getting the environment and the correseponding variable , and then updating it before calling the mock server

So when we call the mock server , it always gets the updated value.

you can store the update variable request in a variable as

```
pm.variable.set("request",pm.request)
```

and then use it in pre-prequest as

```
pm.sendRequest(pm.variables.get("request"))
```

Comment: I'm new so I'm still not understanding a couple of things.  If I want to have the response body return a random number of 10 digits, what is the code for that and where am I putting it?  You reference "pm.variable.set("request",pm.request)" but I'm not sure hwo that relates to my question or where that would go.

Comment: Here I am writing the code to generate random 10 digit code in the pre request section . And then updating the environment variable with that value using postman API ,

Comment: Still not getting it, but appreciate your response.